# Using Try Catch or check value first

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, frameworks

I need to know what is better (for performance and else), Using Try Catch when expecting error and there is no alternate scenario when error hapened or check the value first ?

For Example (VB.net):
 If I need to fill text box by value from database (from Data Reader for example), and I expecting some null values, and if value is null I will leave textbox empty.

now I have to ways to do this:

```
try
  textbox1.text = DR("Name")
catch
end try
```

now if column Name contain null value the error will raise and textbox1 still empty.

```
If Not IsDBNull(DR("Name")) Then textbox1.Text = DR("Name")
```

what is better ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: You should definitelly avoid any try/catches whenever you can. Try is almost free, but when the exception is thrown, than catch is very expensive (talking about performance)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do **not** use exception handling as flow control. Ever.

So - check the value instead of `Try/Catch`.

When an exception is thrown the runtime has quite a lot of work to do - if you expect `null` values - always check for them instead of relying on exceptions.